# Get value from cell and save as variable

Tags: php, cell, phpexcel, import-from-excel

I downloaded the phpexcel lib. What I want to do is simple: Open an .xls file that is in the same directory, read a specific cell and save the value as a variable (only letters and numbers are in the cell).

What I have so far:

```
<?php 

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc/Classes    /PHPExcel.php';

$inputFileName = 'inventory.xls';

/** Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

// Get cell B8
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 2)->getValue();

?>
```

Comment: So assign the result of the `getValue()` call to a variable.... `$variableWhereYouWantToStoreTheValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 2)->getValue();` This really is PHP 101

Comment: im very sorry, i dont know how i could have been so stupid xDD
thank you a ton ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is literally all you need to do:

```
$value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 2)->getValue();
```

I have no idea how you managed to use the PHPExcel library which is full OOP but had no idea how to assign a value to a basic PHP variable...

Comment: Thank you very much, now the next question: after i read the variable and preocess it (cant show this part of the code but what i get in the end is $inhalt
and i want to write that right next to the cell i read 
example: like in the script i get the value from (0,2)  and want to set the cell (1,2) to $inhalt


    $inputFileName = 'inventory.xls';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 2, '$inhalt');
 
Somehow doesnt work

Comment: You are saving the file again after your change to the cell, aren't you?

Comment: no i´m not as i cant find a save function in the docu

Comment: Try removing the quotes from `'$inhalt'`. You're setting the value of the cell to the literal string "$inhalt". You just pass the function `$inhalt` to use the value of the variable.

Comment: There's a whole section of the [documentation about reading and writing files](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md); and almost every single example in the `/Examples` folder demonstrates how to save a file